# User profile badges overview

Tags: discussion, feature-request, badges, profile-page

I always struggle with the badges section in a user's profile. There's simply no overview.

Why don't have a [badges page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges) like on my own profile, but for a different user?
It should be accessable through the user profile.